# JSF 2 set value with js function

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I understand how can I change the value of a given jsf tag (e.g. button label), depending on backing bean value. Though I was thinking if there is a possibility to set the value according to a js function's return value.

I would imagine something like onclick have:

> value ="calljsfunction()"

where the return value would be the value of the button, though I can not find any syntax, that would work.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: I think not possible. JavaScript function can be executed on some event like page load, onclick etc and 'value' attribute is not event. If you want to achieve such functionality, set value of the button on page load (onload event)

Comment: Thank  you very much! It really make sense if you describe it like this!

Answer (score 0):

Bind the button value from Backing bean variable and initialize variable buttonName on event preRenderView

```
<ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{myBean.initBean()}" />
    </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
<h:commandButton value="#{myBean.buttonName}" action="#{myBean.execute()}" /> 



 @ManagedBean
 @RequestScoped
 public class MyBean {
     private String buttonName;
     public String getButtonName() {
         return buttonName;
     }
     public void setButtonName(String buttonName) {
         this.buttonName= buttonName;
     }
  public void initBean(){
      setButtonName("Submit");
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Albin, are you sure, that you answered the question (is it possible to set the value parameter as a return value of a js function instead of the return value of a backing bean value). Or do I understand something incorrectly? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: "I understand how can I change the value of a given jsf tag (e.g. button label), depending on backing bean value" - this is a part from your question, thats y i answered like that.

Answer (score 0):

For setting value of the button through JavaScript, you can use onload event and set button value -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            // write your logic for finding value of the button
            document.getElementById("myForm:button").value = "Submit";
            // or 
            // document.getElementById("myForm:button").value = getValue();
            // function getValue() { return "submit"; } 

        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h2>JSF 2</h2>
    <h:form id="myForm">Type your name here :
           <h:inputText value="#{helloWorld.name}"></h:inputText>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h:commandButton id="button" style="margin-left:120px;" value=""
            action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

You can also put your JavaScript code in a separate .js file